# trash layout like launcher android? is it possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, icons, launcher, recycle-bin

is possible implement  trash layout like launcher android?
In my app, move icon from layout and I would remove it in this layout like "disappearance".

For example press and hold icon I want to remove. then drag it into the layout "trashcan", after this layout disappears.

thanks

Comment: Source code for launcher is available, have you looked at it?

Comment: I solved with hide actionbar and layout that substitute it.